# Multi-line string with lines ending in a slash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a multi-line string cleanly which includes backslashes and variable substitution. Originally, I did not need backslashes and was able to achieve what I needed with this snippet:

```
            description=$(cat <<EOF
Creation time: $(date)
Creator: $test_group_creator
Test group: $test_group
Test execution: $test_execution_id - $test_name
Adapter: $initiator1_mac_addr

http://...
EOF
)
```

It's not ideal as it looks a little clunky at the end and requires I break the indentation level of the code, but it's pretty clear and represents how the description will appear on a webpage later. (I am aware of the <<-EOF syntax, but we are using 4-space indents in code and that syntax requires tabs.) Here is the variable echoed out:

```
Creation time: Tue Jun 27 15:22:27 PDT 2017
Creator: langlorx
Test group: all
Test execution: 13 - go
Adapter: eth0

link...
```

However, recently, the text has been also dropped into a Wiki parser and now line-breaks are collapsed to a single space. To force a line-break mid-paragraph, the line must end in a double backslash. Knowing that bash treats backslashes specially, I knew I had to double up on the double-backslashes, but it still didn't come out right. Using this:

```
            description=$(cat <<EOF
Creation time: $(date)\\\\
Creator: $test_group_creator\\\\
Test group: $test_group\\\\
Test execution: $test_execution_id - $test_name\\\\
Adapter: $initiator1_mac_addr\\\\

http://...
EOF
)
```

I find that the newlines are completely gone in the resulting variable, and last \\\\ sequence before the blank line results in a single backslash in the variable with the blank line completely gone. Without any backslashes, the resulting string comes out exactly as written above with newlines, blank lines and with the variables substituted. Once I include any backslashes at the end of a line, it triggers a different set of rules in bash for encoding the variable.

```
Creation time: Tue Jun 27 15:20:17 PDT 2017\\Creator: user\\Test group: all\\Test execution: 12 - go\\Adapter: eth0\link...
```

Is there a better way to do this in bash than trying to abuse cat and command-substitution while still having the code somewhat clean?

Answer (score 2):

Store the data in the format you want it, and then just postprocess as necessary. If you want to ignore leading spaces and append `\\` to each line, just do that:

```
embed() { sed -e 's/^ *//; s/$/\\\\/'; }

description=$(embed << eof
    Creation time: $(date)
    Creator: foo
    Test group: bar
    etc
eof
)

printf '%s\n' "$description"
```

will give you:

```
Creation time: Tue Jun 27 15:33:31 PDT 2017\\
Creator: foo\\
Test group: bar\\
etc\\
```